# SQL естественное соединение

Tags: c#, sql

Возникла проблема с запросом естественного соединения. Создал запрос при создании DataAdapter `select * from table1 natural join table2`, но команда `dataAdapter.fill(dataSet)` завершилась исключением `Сбой IErrorInfo.GetDescription с E_FAIL(0x80004005).` что это может быть?

```
dataSet = new DataSet();
dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from table1 natural join table2", connection);
dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "Продажи");
sale.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["Продажи"];
```

Comment: Весь код покажите

Comment: Выполните этот запрос непосредственно в вашей БД и посмотрите работает ли он

Answer (score 0):

Вы скорее всего обращайтесь к SQL Server или MS Access. Они не поддерживают natural join. Используйте обычный inner join с явным перечислением колонок.

Comment: тогда зачем еще нужны связи таблиц кроме поддержки обновления связанных полей

Comment: @НиколайСтавцев Единственное назначение связи таблиц - обеспечение ссылочной целостности, что бы в одной таблице не могли существовать данные, указывающие на что то, чего нет в другой таблице. кроме того обратите внимание, в тех СУБД где natural join поддерживается, он выполняет связь по _всем одноименным полям_, ни на какие ключи и связи он при этом не смотрит.